# Picking a Lyapunov function that is dependent on time

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I have the following system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x_{1}}(t) = x_{2} - x_{1}^{3}\\
\dot{x_{2}}(t) = -0.5 x_{1} - x_{2} + d\sin(t)
\end{cases}  
$$

where $d$ is some constant.

I want to show $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable. I am trying to find the coefficients with the candidate $V(x) = A x_{1}^{2} + B x_{2}^{2}$. I find that $A = 1$ and $B = 2$.

This gives me $V(x) = x_{1}^{2} + 2x_{2}^{2}$.

Taking the derivative I get:

$$
\dot{V} = -2(x_{1}^{4} + 2 x_{2}^{2}) + 4d \sin(t) 
$$

I stuck with the term that is dependent on $t$.

Any hints or ideas I could get rid of the term dependent on $t$?

Comment: $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$ is not a solution of your system. It does not have stationary solutions.

Comment: Your last term is missing a factor $x_2$ from $\dot V=2x_1\dot x_1+4x_2\dot x_2$.